# restart iot edge runtime using a module and invoked methods

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

I'm very new with Azure and IoT Edge, and I'm trying to understand how modules works.

If I have an iot edge device run on Linux OS, and I would like to build a module in case I invoke it, it will restart the iot edge runtime (edge Deamon). Whatever the language that will be used, how should the code with the iot edge runtime, any ideas

I need to do this for  for re-provisining purposes. In case that I want to change the configuration of the device, then u need to re-provision, in this case as far as I understand, either u reboot the hardware, or restart the iot edge runtime.

I am thinking of this work around as Invoked methods does not support the restart of the runtime so far.

Comment: Could you be more specific on why you would like to restart the edge runtime that way?

Comment: @karben for re-provisining purposes. In case that I want to change the configuration of the device, then u need to re-provision, in this case as far as I understand, either u reboot the hardware, or restart the iot edge runtime. Invoked methods does not support the restart of the runtime so far, so I was thinking of a work around ...

Comment: Would it suffice to simply restart one of your custom Edge modules? I don't think you can restart the entire Edge service but Edge 1.0.9 includes the ability to restart a module via a direct method: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iotedge/releases/tag/1.0.9

Comment: @Mark the point of the remote restart is for re.provisioning scenario, and restarting a module without the runtime, would not help in that case.

Comment: @AhmedEssam I'm not sure if you want to restart the edgeHub and edgeAgent or restart the edge daemon. The latter I doubt is possible. You would need to execute a command on the host from within a docker container and you would have to be root when you did it. Restarting the containers might be possible via the docker API but, again, I don't know if you could actually do that from a container.

Comment: @MarkRadbourne I want to restart the edge deamon in order to re-initiate the re-provision of the device (changing IoT Hub or updating x509 scenarios). I am trying to think of a solution to do that using a container that would communicate with the host machine as external source. I dont like it but apparently its the  feasible option so far.

Comment: @AhmedEssam I can't think of a clean and secure mechanism to do that. I don't know what it is you need to modify to "reprovision" and why that would entail restarting the daemon. It really doesn't do much other than read the config.yaml and start edgeAgent.

Comment: @MarkRadbourne I will try to give a more clear scenario in case I wasn't clear or that I am missing something, I have a device that exists in a field with 3G connection, that is configured and provisioned via DPS. At some point,I would like to move it to another IoT Hub,so I change the configuration in the DPS enrollment,then to re-configure the device, in theory I need to re-start the daemon so that with the config.yaml it will contact the DPS and get the new configuration.As I understand,everytime the daemon starts it will contact the DPS to make sure of the configurations in the yaml,right?

Comment: @AhmedEssam You are correct. If you modify your DPS service and want IoT Edge to reconnect to pick up a different target IoTHub then you would need to restart the daemon. Restarting the daemon from a Docker container is not likely to have an elegant solution.

Comment: @MarkRadbourne I fully agree with that it isnt an elegant solution, I will doubt the stability of such a solution as well, and thats why I am looking for any ideas or workarounds.

Comment: @AhmedEssam I doubt you will get anything useful. My best suggestion is that you come up with a design that does not require you to move an IoT Edge from one hub to another. I don't really see what benefit you would gain from that action.